# bash yad and gnu parallel: multi-progress bar

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, yad

If you run the following:

```
func() {
sleep 0.3
}
export -f func
percent1=0
for n in {1..4} ; do
    seq 30 | parallel -j 5 --bar func {} 2> >(yad --width=500 --progress --auto-close)
    let percent1+=25
    echo "1:$percent1"
done |
yad \
--height=300 \
--multi-progress \
--auto-close \
--bar="Bar 1 :":NORM \
--bar="Bar 2 :":NORM
```

2 windows will appear:

- The first one stays open and contains 2 progress bars. "Bar 1" shows the progress of the "for" loop and "Bar 2" does nothing.
- The other window keeps closing and reopening and shows the progress of the GNU parallel process that re-runs at each iteration of the "for" loop.

What I want is, instead of having 2 windows, to redirect the second progress into the "Bar 2" of the first window so that I only have one window that stays open and nothing popping in and out repeatedly.

I've searched and tried for hours and would love some pointers.